# subtract two order-less std::vector of objects

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have two vectors of object. Something like:

```
std::vector<thing> all_things;
std::vector<thing> bad_things;
```

I want to obtain a third vector that contains the **good_things**. In other words, every object in **all_thing** that is not belong to **bad_things**:

```
std::vector<thing> good_things=subtract(all_things,bad_things);
```

Any Ideas about how to implement **subtract** in most efficient  and standard way.

P.S the vectors can **NOT** be ordered because the class **thing** does not have any thing to be ordered by. 
Thanks!

Edit:
and I do not want to make any change to `all_things`.
e.g.

```
void substract(const std::vector<thing>& a, const std::vector<thing>& b);
```

Comment: are the elements in your vectors unique?

Comment: consider using `std::set`

Comment: @PaoloM [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) requires a sorting (which the OP states is not possible), he should therefore use a [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) if the elements are unique

Comment: Does `thing` have an appropriate `operator==` or equivalent?

Comment: @m.s. yes it is unique

Comment: I think the "thing" class should have an operator== overload like AndyG is suggesting, as your code will have to check for equivalence of "thing" objects. 
The answer given by mkaes doesn't seem to compile either, without the operator overload.
After adding the operator it should be a trivial task of making a loop within a loop and generating the "good_things" vector.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining something that cannot have an order. If all else fails use `memcmp` with `std::sort` and then do linear erasing.

Comment: @nwp :
class thing{
private:
cv::Mat some_photo;
}
....      of course cv::Mat is something like bitmap

Comment: So why don't you sort `thing` by the RGB-values of the bitmap?

Comment: is it even make sense ? what about the cost?

Comment: You can trust `memcmp` to be extremely well optimized. And chances are you only compare a couple of bytes. If you can `move` `thing`s efficiently you can just sort. If not you can make sure to insert them in the correct position when created. Another way would be to keep a `vector<thing *> good;` that you update on every insert/removal. The most efficient algorithm of `subtract` is to just not need it, which seems quite doable.

Comment: @nwp I think that I have misunderstood something.. ordering should not be meaning full.. it could be any kind of meaningless ordering.. is this right or wrong ?

Comment: Can a `thing` have a meaningless, but logically correct, ordering added?  What does `==` do to a `thing`?  Is it practical to hash a `thing`?  Can we add a field to cache the hash and have that cache be reliable?

Comment: I think so.. maybe my question is ordered now which is easy to solve. However, I do not want to change it cause the order-less case maybe interesting too!

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Just make sure it is actually a (total) [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). Ordering pokemon by type advantage doesn't work because it doesn't have an order, but ordering them by alphabet works. Using `random` does not produce an ordering, using `memcmp` does. And of course you need to be consistent and not change the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, your `thing`s can be sorted, but in a meaningless way.

And that is ok.

Sort them meaninglessly.

Write a function that takes two `thing`s and give them a meaningless order that is consistent, and two things only compare not-less-than each other if they are equal.

Call this `bool arb_order_thing(thing const&, thing const&)`.

Now `std::sort` both vectors and use `std::set_difference`.

Now, this can be expensive if things are expensive to copy.  So instead create two vectors of `thing const*`, write `bool arb_order_thing_ptr(thing const*, thing const*)` (which dereferences and compares using the meaningless ordering), sort the vectors-of-pointers using that, use set_difference using that, then convert back to a `vector<thing>`.

Alternatively, consider writing a `thing const*` hasher (not a `std::hash<thing*>`, because that is global and rude) and use `unordered_set<thing const*>`s to do the work manually.  Hash the smaller of the two vectors, then do a `std::copy_if` testing against the hash on the other vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't order them, you can use the brute force way. Just compare the vectors. E.g:

```
std::vector<Thing> all;
std::vector<Thing> bad;
std::vector<Thing> good (all.size());
auto it = std::copy_if (all.begin(), all.end(), good.begin(), 
    [&bad](const Thing& t){return std::find(bad.begin(), bad.end(), t) == bad.end();} );
all.resize(std::distance(all.begin(),it));
```

Comment: Why do you resize `all`? Why do you leave the the entries in the sub-range [`it`, `good.end()`) partially formed?

Comment: +1 Also, don't feel bad about using brute force with a std::vector rather than using another container.  Depending on your circumstances it might actually be the fastest approach, thanks to the fact that vector places its values in a single contiguous allocation.

Comment: The last row does not seem to work. [Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c702314ff6dbab5)

Comment: Why do you default-construct so many `Thing`s in `good` which is useless and avoidable?

Comment: @NickyC: Because it is a friggin example. You could just use a back inserter and don't resize. This highly depends on the use case. So for the question it is rather pointless how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

If `thing` is expensive to construct/copy and its container is long and bads are overwhelming, it is not a good idea to construct a same long 'not bad' array. Actually a flag matrix of all.size() x good.size() have to be filled based on `thing` comparison. If unicity is ensured iterating through bads could be spared. But O(N<sup>2</sup>) is the complexity anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest code similar to mkaes, but with few adjustments:

```
std::vector<thing> substract(const std::vector<thing>& a, const std::vector<thing>& b) {
    std::vector<thing> sub;
    sub.reserve(a.size());
    for (const auto &item : a) {
        if (std::find(b.begin(), b.end(), item) == b.end()) {
             sub.push_back(a);
        }
    }
    return sub;
}
```

It's brutal version of what you want to achieve. But it's the best you can do, if you can't sort elements of vectors. Remember though, that you need to be able to compare two objects of `item` type, meaning you will need to provide `operator==`.

Comment: Improve? Maybe not, but it doesn't unnecessarily trigger `all.size()` default constructors. Default constructor for `thing` type doesn't even have to exist. Still it's better to call `reserve` than trigger reallocation.